# Type inference in a use of "correlated union" pattern

Tags: typescript, type-inference

Here's a factory class, which constructs objects, making use of the "correlated union" pattern:

```
interface Factory<FT, N extends keyof FT> {
  (f: CompositeFactory<FT>): FT[N]
}

// The following two types are motivated by allowing the return type of
// CompositeFactory.make to be determined by its `name` argument type, using the
// correlated union pattern.
type FactoryWithName<FT, K extends keyof FT> = {
  [N in K]: {
    name: N
    factory: Factory<FT, N>
  }
}[K]
export type FactoriesWithNameByName<FT> = { [N in keyof FT]: FactoryWithName<FT, N> }

// Motivated by making constructing CompositeFactory concise
export type FactoriesObject<FT> = { [N in keyof FT]: Factory<FT, N> }

export class CompositeFactory<FT> {
  private factories: FactoriesWithNameByName<FT>
  constructor(factories: FactoriesObject<FT>) {
    this.factories = Object.fromEntries(
      Object.entries(factories).map(([n, f]) => [n, {name: n, factory: f}])
    ) as FactoriesWithNameByName<FT>
  }
  make<N extends keyof FT>(name: N): FT[N] {
    return this.factories[name].factory(this)
  }
}
```

Currently, that can be used like this (with an explicit type declaration on the first line):

```
const factories: FactoriesObject<{
  foo: number
  thing: { size: number }
}> = {
  foo: () => 123,
  thing: (f) => {
    const x = f.make("foo")
    return { size: x }
  },
}
const f = new CompositeFactory(factories)
const thing = f.make("thing")
console.log(JSON.stringify(thing))
```

I'd like to use it something like this (without the explicit type declaration, since that information is present in the factory functions):

```
const factories2 = {
  foo: () => 123,
  thing: (f) => { // Error: Parameter 'f' implicitly has an 'any' type.
    const x = f.make("foo")
    return { size: x }
  },
}
const f2 = new CompositeFactory(factories2)
const thing2 = f.make("thing")
console.log(JSON.stringify(thing2))
```

Of course I can add an explicit `f: any` type declaration to make the error go away, but I'd prefer if the compiler knew the precise type in the implementation of that function.

Is that, or something like it, possible?

Comment: I think this has less to do with correlated unions and more to do with inferring generic type arguments, which does not happen for types.  You can use a helper function to give you such inference; it looks like [this](https://tsplay.dev/m36JqN) (and note that the most precise type it can infer looks like `{foo: number; thing: unknown}` because the compiler cannot do multiple simultaneous rounds of generic-and-callback-contextual inference).  If you want better inference *there* I can imagine a builder pattern if you want to see it.  Does this address your question fully? If so I could...

Comment: ...write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: The builder pattern seems like a different problem.  I think your comment probably answers it by itself if you were to paste it in :-)  (though I don't fully understand what "multiple simultaneous rounds of generic-and-callback-contextual inference" means -- I think I get the gist very vaguely though: I guess the type of `f` isn't known when considering `thing`, because that needs the type of `thing`).  I'm sure you're aware, but you can get the same `unknown` type for the `thing` value by omitting the intermediate `factories2` variable, instead passing the object direct to `CompositeFactory`.

Comment: ... although it would be interesting to see your rendering of the builder pattern here anyway :-)  Also I'm never 100% sure I know exactly what people have in mind with pattern names...

Comment: I'm thinking something like [this](https://tsplay.dev/wj1bvW) where you build up your object in stages so that you're not asking the compiler to infer callback parameter contextual types and generic type arguments at the same time.  That is better than just getting `unknown` for `thing` I guess.  Anyway, I'm happy to write all of this up as an answer, if that works for you.

Comment: Ah, a builder for the CompositeFactory, yes that seems like a nice solution!  I think an answer with what you did there and explaining the inference problem with my solution similarly to your first comment would be perfect, thank you so much.

Comment: Possible different solution: I think I had in mind earlier incrementally constructing new CompositeBuilders by adding new factory functions, without the builder (then I got a bit lost in the type-weeds).  If I implement that and it turns out OK I'll add it here as a secondary answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to explicitly [annotate](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-annotations-on-variables) the type of `factories` as `FactoriesObject<{ foo: number; thing: { size: number }}>` then you'll have to figure out how to get the TypeScript compiler to *infer* it.  Maybe you'd like to be able to say something like

```
// not valid TS, don't do this
const factories: FactoriesObject<infer> = {
  foo: () => 123,
  thing: (f) => {
    const x = f.make("foo")
    return { size: x }
  },
}
```

where `infer` would tell the compiler to infer the type argument `T` to `FactoriesObject`, and then the compiler would use this context to also [contextually infer](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-inference.html#contextual-typing) that `f` is of type `CompositeFactory<T>`.

There are two problems with this, though.

---

The first problem is that you can't get the compiler to infer type arguments in generic types from values of those types. That `FactoriesObject<infer>` syntax is not valid.  There's an open issue at [microsoft/TypeScript#32794](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/32794) asking for some way to do this, but so far it's not part of the language.

This problem can be overcome though, by replacing `const factories: FactoriesObject<infer> = {...}` by `const factories = asFactoriesObject({...})` for an appropriately defined `asFactoriesObject` helper function:

```
const asFactoriesObject = <T,>(fo: FactoriesObject<T>) => fo;
```

You can't get the compiler to infer type arguments in generic *types*, but you *can* get it to infer type arguments when calling generic *functions*.  So the above `asFactoriesObject()` is a generic function that returns its input as-is, and lets you use the compiler's inference abilities to get a value of type `FactoriesObject<T>` for an inferred `T`.

Like this:

```
const factories = asFactoriesObject({
  foo: () => 123,
  thing: (f) => {
    // (parameter) f: CompositeFactory<{  foo: number; thing: unknown; }>
    const x = f.make("foo")
    return { size: x }
  },
});
/* const factories: FactoriesObject<{
    foo: number;
    thing: unknown;
}> */
const f = new CompositeFactory(factories)
const thing = f.make("thing") // unknown
```

So `T` is inferred, !  But it's inferred as `{foo: number; thing: unknown}` instead of `{ foo: number; thing: { size: number }}`, .

---

Which brings us to the second problem.  Without explicitly annotating the type argument to `FactoriesObject` and asking the compiler to infer it, you've set up a circular inference task that the compiler isn't great at solving.  The type of `thing` depends on the type of `f` which depends on the type of `thing`.  The compiler gives up and infers `unknown` there instead of `{size: number}`.

This sort of limitation is hard to completely eradicate.  There have actually been some [improvements to simultaneous inference of callback parameter types and generic type arguments](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-7.html#improved-function-inference-in-objects-and-methods) recently, but those involve situations where each callback only depends on previous properties in the object. Whereas here, each callback depends, at least by call signature, on the entire object.  Without something like a *full [unification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unification_(computer_science)#Higher-order_unification) algorithm* as discussed in [microsoft/TypeScript#30134](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30134), this is just not possible.

---

So what can we do instead if you don't want to explicitly annotate the types yourself?  Well, presumably you'll never really have each property depend on every other property.  Instead you probably have an acyclic *chain* where some properties depend on previous properties in the chain.  And if so, you can replace the simple one-shot helper function with a *builder* that assembles the full object from each piece of the chain, giving you inference along the way.

There are lots of ways to implement this, but I'll present one which ends up passing the composed object to the `CompositeFactory` constructor at the end.  You could put this inside `CompositeFactory` if you want.  You could make it so that the links in the chain are passed by separate key/value arguments instead of by sub-objects.  There are probably more possibilities.  The idea here is just to show you how it's possible to get the inference you want:

```
interface CompositeFactoryBuilder<T extends object> {
  and<U extends { [K in keyof U]: K extends keyof T ? never : unknown }>(
    fo: { [K in keyof U]: (f: CompositeFactory<T>) => U[K] }
  ): CompositeFactoryBuilder<{ [K in keyof (T & U)]: (T & U)[K] }>,
  build(): CompositeFactory<T>
}

function compositeFactoryBuilderOf<T extends object>(
  fo: { [K in keyof T]: (f: CompositeFactory<{}>) => T[K] }
): CompositeFactoryBuilder<T> {
  return ({
    and(fo2) {
      return compositeFactoryBuilderOf({ ...fo, ...fo2 } as any);
    },
    build() {
      return new CompositeFactory(fo);
    }
  });
}
```

So the `compositeFactoryBuilderOf()` takes an initial object whose methods don't depend on anything (they accept `CompositeFactory<{}>` which might as well not even  be an argument) and returns a `CompositeFactoryBuilder<T>` object for an appropriate type `T`.  This object has an `and()` method which will take another object whose methods accept `CompositeFactory<T>`, and return something like a `CompositeFactoryBuilder<T & U>` for the original `T` and the extra properties represented by `U`.  You can keep calling `and()` and pass extra links in the chain.  When you're done you can call `build()`, which gives you the `CompositeFactory<T & U & V & ....>` for the whole thing.

Let's test it:

```
const f = compositeFactoryBuilderOf({ foo: () => 123 }).
  and({ thing: f => { const x = f.make("foo"); return { size: x } } }).
  //           ^<-- f: CompositeFactory<{ foo: number }>
  build();
/* const f: CompositeFactory<{
    foo: number;
    thing: {
        size: number;
    };
}> */
const thing = f.make("thing")
console.log(JSON.stringify(thing)) // {size: 123}
```

Looks good.  The call to `compositeFactoryBuilderOf({foo: ()=>123})` produces a `CompositeFactoryBuilder<{foo: number}>`.  Then in the call to `and()`, the callback in the `thing` property is contextually inferred to have its `f` parameter be of type `CompositeFactory<{foo: number}>`.  This produces a `CompositeFactoryBuilder<{foo: number; thing: {size: number}}>`.  That's what we wanted, so we call `build()`, giving us the final `CompositeFactory<{foo: number; thing: {size: number}}>`, which behaves as expected.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=9&noErrorTruncation=true#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEApeIA2AvJBvAUEkgJbAAuEATgGYLIBiCZA9pQJ4A8AKgDRIDSSCAA8KwACZQkAawhtm1JFwB8eQkSQAKagC4kAYWZgYzKMQqN4Ldt2UBKPVwDa-ALrqAvvnUB6H0oALZGpmDAxmAHdSAHMkMgjmOLYYaCQQSmQwZjJiADcQCnEkACM2NLDImLigpAyyAFdKYCSUpAVff0NjU3MIS2s2ADowEFk4xOLkcQgKSjBSCCLSkjIpAANQSDW0ymj6yHIWiD56s2BYsiCOpHhWDIwCxaR64GJmZrgyWeBB9TJkhhMVhsADq5gCADlwBBuHxBCIxJIZHIFEpVABeNQaJBOAAKJGabj0BGxRE2ED0uPU2NoVmBen6wNhSFxympSC8RA8LncRH+rUZlGI0DBlyhkAAQmxxTCVEhMbgcYJSMj5IouK4GUD2KLIdDmfxVF5rgBZbJ5R5LMojaRVW7AKBkSj1KxVLomMwWbVle3wYhQCB-AFIQXCqAAeWKACsIFZbPK8Dj8SrZGqlJqQ97mayOd4iPAHlApO6el66TY5SSNDAhfkKEhadYw1ry2HdTKpTLbOz7Y7neXtNrm5nW9BIzG4yo7FjSZd-YNG6wwwnx7GyAvKEYAKLkIXQTTs7GrqyDCC7sOD0dQOzDEAwTSaJzAPjUVzT9GqJ98RXkvTPhvenoigeG+h5INOIBSKGIrgh20r6io7KchoNowvCohnkiqaoiomi-gIDhKDyM7YnUjTNHOUALkO0BPtCrjUeWbCaJRdhIZ43jqOSsB0CGxCUI6XDsGoPbvI6aRQNBEbRmuCawso2jMC2TZjjJk72PKqghAA3KJDpkABV4JpBUnHmQmhVjSzBKVo76qAAjAATAAzDwYFzucejaHZJGkn4WhwJQ0KzNOugGEYHq9IKnCKg21l-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-nrvAkXnuVmBTXNBZetpBIimOdOPOkuPeeRYP7DD5QJcWUggw7yEfA7wuzCORyEnT2w-VTz1U9x4zie+QVS8XVdrfRYpF8Nb3pIeO-GjGtiRUNgTLcAebch7x2LtQLey1bK2ycs5DkN4wJ83EFvTaQFbaKgASVTEZVUJVRqnVFKS9FStXap1E+39fgFX8h-IgAA9DgABaRhDYW7JzplmRU0DgCJXVnlMCN8E4-yIMNUa+lWHXRXqAmwC99bxRVrw5KU80H3waqQlaa1L77R1kgI6z1UrnDengyqX16qFTEuDSGzBoZwwRkjJ0KM0YsQCDETGP1-C4HUUgOBf9cz4A8EAA)

Comment: The nice part about this is that I think this better fits my needs even ignoring typing (so I already planned to do something like this) - but I didn't spot that that would help with type inference.  In fact I suspected that typing would get in the way of this sort of dynamic construction, which is part of why I didn't start this way!

Answer (score 0):

A variation on @jcalz's solution (needs some cleaning up but shows the idea).

Factories that depend on each other are added separately using `.withFactory` (instead of via a separate builder as in jcalz's solution, or at construction time as in my question).

Here it is:

```
interface Factory<FT, N extends keyof FT> {
  (f: CompositeFactory<FT>): FT[N]
}

// The folloowing two types are motivated by correlated union to allow the
// return type of CompositeFactory.make to be determined by its `name` argument
type FactoryWithName<FT, K extends keyof FT> = {
  [N in K]: {
    name: N
    factory: Factory<FT, N>
  }
}[K]
export type FactoriesWithNameByName<FT> = { [N in keyof FT]: FactoryWithName<FT, N> }

// Motivated by making constructing CompositeFactory concise
export type FactoriesObject<FT> = { [N in keyof FT]: Factory<FT, N> }

export class CompositeFactory<FT> {
  private factories: FactoriesWithNameByName<FT>
  private fo: FactoriesObject<FT>
  constructor(fo: FactoriesObject<FT>) {
    this.fo = fo
    this.factories = Object.fromEntries(
      Object.entries(fo).map(([n, f]) => [n, {name: n, factory: f}])
    ) as FactoriesWithNameByName<FT>
  }
  withFactory<U>(fo: { [K in keyof U]: (f: CompositeFactory<FT>) => U[K] }): CompositeFactory<FT & U > {
    return new CompositeFactory({ ...this.fo, ...fo }) as any;
  }
  make<N extends keyof FT>(name: N): FT[N] {
    return this.factories[name].factory(this)
  }
}

let f = new CompositeFactory({ color: () => "red" })
  .withFactory({
    foo: (_) => 123,
  })
  .withFactory({
    thing: (f) => ({
      door: f.make("foo"),
    }),
  })

const thing = f.make("thing")
console.log(JSON.stringify(thing))
```